# How to Track response time by nginx-sflow-module

Tags: nginx, benchmarking, ganglia

I have installed ganglia and Host sflowd to track a number of performance indicators on my web servers. I'm using nginx-sflow-module to enable Http performance reports from servers. However I could not find any metric that indicates response time for each HTTP request on the application server. Am I missing something or there must be a separate script to calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

The [sflowtool](https://github.com/sflow/sflowtool) command line utility can be used to print the sFlow data, an example of the output is included in the [nginx-sflow-module](https://github.com/sflow/nginx-sflow-module) README. HTTP response time is reported in the http_duration_uS attribute. The sflowtool -H option converts the binary sFlow into standard combined logfile format for use with a logfile analyzer. There is a list of additional sFlow analysis and reporting tools on sFlow.org.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Actually  I can see some of the http metrics like HTTP status, PUT, GET, OPTION, ... in the ganglia web page. But this metric, http_duration_uS , I'm not sure how I can add it to ganglia metrics to be shown on the page. with sflowtool I can collect these metrics, but I need them to be collected in ganglia rrd files.